# Wrapping div around appended div in jQuery not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code below. I'd like wrap each `$containerCard` in an enclosing div for styling purposes. I tried `wrap()` but it didn't see to do what I've intended (it's adding 3 of the same div since it's in the for loop and gets 3 results). I am trying to take the results of a JSON object and do a responsive layout.

Here's the HTML

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="cards" >
     <!-- Would like to wrap each set of appended divs in one enclosing div called "card" -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

And the JS

```
 var $container = $('.container');
 var $containerCard = $container.find('.cards');

  $.each(json.screens[0].config.views, function(index, element) {
  $containerCard.wrap('<div class="card">');
  $containerCard.append('<div class="card-title"' +  '">' + element.title +  '</div>' );
  $containerCard.append('<div class="card-image"' +  '">' + '<img src="' + element.thumbnail + '"/>' +  '</div>');
  $containerCard.append('<div class="card-content"' +  '">' + element.info +  '</div>' );
  $containerCard.append('<div class="card-description"' +  '">' + element.description +  '</div>' );
});
```

Comment: Thanks yeah append just adds the div to the top of that collection. Just wanted a div to wrap all of the others per result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want each of your content items to be wrapped in a `<div class="card">`, then create that div, append all the content to it, and append that `card` div to your card container, like so:

```js
var json = { screens: [{config: {views: [
  {title: "title 1", info :"info 1", description: "description 1"},
  {title: "title 2", info :"info 2", description: "description 2"},
  {title: "title 3", info :"info 3", description: "description 3"}
]}}]};

var $container = $('.container');
var $containerCard = $container.find('.cards');

$.each(json.screens[0].config.views, function(index, element) {
  //Create the card
  var $card = $("<div class='card' />");
 
  //Append the data to it
  $card.append('<div class="card-title"' + '">' + element.title + '</div>');
  $card.append('<div class="card-image"' + '">' + '<img src="' + element.thumbnail + '"/>' + '</div>');
  $card.append('<div class="card-content"' + '">' + element.info + '</div>');
  $card.append('<div class="card-description"' + '">' + element.description + '</div>');

  //Add the card to the container
  $containerCard.append($card);
});
```

```css
.card { margin: 5px; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="cards"></div>
</div>
```